# Nodejs SSL using CloudFlare not working over https

Tags: node.js, https, socket.io, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

So the problem I'm having is that the client won't connect with the server.js when the server.js is using https.

if I go to "https://mydomainame.com" I get this error in the console of every other browser than brave browser
index.js:83 GET https://serverip:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NK0oCD6 net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
[image]

(The blacked out is the IP address of the server)
the weird thing is that in the brave browser the domain changes to "http://mydomainame.com" and the client then is connected to server.js
[image]

I'm using free Cloudflare with Full end to end encryption
[image]

server.js code:

```
var express = require('express'),
https = require('https');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var httpsOptions = { 
    key: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/ssl/sitename.com.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/ssl/sitename.com.pem')};
var server = https.createServer(httpsOptions,app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

const port = 8081;
server.listen(port);
```

And client.js connection code:

```
socket = io.connect('https://serverip:8081', {secure: true});
```

I am using the same Origin Certificates for the server and for the nodejs code.
The server is using Apache2 with PHPMyAdmin and is configured to make the domain only work using https.

I read somewhere something Cloudflare not being able to use other ports than 443 and some other but I did not really understand it, And I can't get the server.js to work over port 443.

I'm thankful for any information or help I can get! :)

Comment: Yes CloudFlare does not support non-443 ports, and your client code is not connecting to CF either, you are connecting directly to `serverip` which is the origin server. In this case, nodejs will serve the CF origin certificate to your browser, and since the origin certificate is for specific use with CF, your browser will report certificate error.

Comment: Oh okay. What do you recommend I should do? make the node code use port 443 and connect thru it using the CF IP address. if that is even possible. or should I get a different Certificate for the node code? I'm kind of new to all this stuff! Tnx for the reply :)

Comment: yes, make your nodejs listen on 443 is the way to go

Comment: @EricWong I Checked this article [Cloudflare article ](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Identifying-network-ports-compatible-with-Cloudflare-s-proxy&usg=ALkJrhg-Y6wcA0B_3vzctwECQlvscGKjWg) and it says that they also alow a few other ports over https. So when I changed in my code to port 8443. And also changed `socket = io.connect('https://domainname.com:8443', {secure: true});` and now I get this error in the console [link to img](https://ibb.co/gWxr4QK)

Comment: is your site running on domainname.com default port 80 or 443? you are seeing [CORS problems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) which is whole other topic

Comment: @EricWong its on domainname.com port 443. The weird thing is that I didn't have the CORS Problems when the node code was on HTTP. And I haven't changed any code at all in the nodejs that would make any difference. I haven't really had time to look into the CORS Error but I have tried some fixes [link](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled) but none have worked. And if it helps I don't have any GET or POST request in my code. Just find it weird cus I should have gotten the CORS problem while on HTTP right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I figured it out, big thanks to Eric Wong for pointing out the biggest problem that I was trying to connect to the server using its IP there for not going thru Cloudflare.

Then in this article [Identifying network ports compatible with Cloudflare's proxy](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Identifying-network-ports-compatible-with-Cloudflare-s-proxy&usg=ALkJrhg-Y6wcA0B_3vzctwECQlvscGKjWg)
 you can see what ports Cloudflare allows connections on then, I changed my code to used the https port 8443.

```
socket = io.connect('https://domainname.com:8443',{secure: true});
```

then the only thing I had to do was to port forward the new port and everything worked fine!

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar problem. What do you mean by "was to port forward the new port"?

Comment: @ArivanBastos Sorry for the late reply. What I meant was that I only needed to port forward the port in my router that I was using for the server. (For me it was port:8443)